# Getting the count of a to-many relationship in core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a data model with a Parent entity and a child entity. The child entity has a to-many inverse relationship with Parent entity (a child can have multiple parents). I am currently trying to get the number of parents a particular child has:

```
Parent *doomedParent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Child *child = [doomedParent valueForKey:@"child"];
int parentCount = [[child valueForKey:@"parents.@count"] intValue];
```

When trying to get the parents (Parent relationship) count from a child I get the following error:

'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Child is not key value coding-compliant for the key "parents.@count".'

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that "parents.@count" is a key. what is the value of the variable intValue ?

Comment: @euphoria83, `"parents.@count"` is called a key path in Cocoa. `intValue` is a message (not a variable) being sent to the result of the `valueForKey:` (sic) message sent to `child`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using `-valueForKeyPath:`, not `-valueForKey:`, which does not follow key paths (`-valueForKey:` is thus faster for single key lookups). This should work:

```
int parentCount = [[child valueForKeyPath:@"parents.@count"] intValue];
```

Comment: Man, I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

While Barry Wark's answer is correct for using KVC, is there any reason you don't just get the count of the `.parents` `NSSet`, like this:

```
NSUInteger parentCount = [child.parents count];
```

KVC is great and all, but unless I'm missing something, isn't it overkill for this situation?